# Microsoft Kinect for Windows Camera driver not found

Tags: camera, driver, kinect

I'm working with Microsoft Kinect for Windows using SDK 1.8.

It automatically finds all of the drivers required, except for the Kinect Camera driver. Because of this, whenever I run a progra,m it gives an exception at: `sensor.Colorstream.Enable();`

When I use Xbox 360 instead it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone please tell me how to get this Kinect for Windows working?

Thanks

Comment: Please add which programming language, if the SDK browser tools work, which demo program you try to run.

Comment: I'm using C# and the SDK tool isn't working as well, im trying to track the skeleton joints

Comment: If the SDK tool is not working, you need to fix the drivers first and get the camera to work. Can you remove all old drivers for the kinect, uninstall the devices of the kinect in the device manager and then reinstall the SDK 1.8 again. Now try to get everything installed correctly in the device manager.

Comment: What happend to me before was that I also had the openNI drivers. It was sometimes hard to switch between the SDK and openNI drivers.

Comment: I removed the SDK 1.7 totally including all the drivers and re installed the SDK 1.8 but that didn't work either. The problem is that the same drivers work perfectly fine with the XBox 360 but not with the Kinect for Windows

Comment: Perhaps the sensor is defect. Good time to contact your supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a similar issue, I just solved it in the following way:

In the device manager the kinect can be recognized in 2 ways:

- Primesense
- Kinect for windows

In my case, it only works when it is installed as Kinect for Windows.

When it is recognized as Primesense, you can do the following for all 3 devices (camera, motor, audio):

- right click: update driver
- Choose 'search on my computer for driver'
- Choose from list of drivers on my computer
- Choose the Kinect for Windows driver

Comment: where would the driver come from?